# How can I emboss a certain part of a label and change the roughness?

Tags: displacement, bump

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first image is the effect I'm trying to aim for, the second image is what I currently have. I'm trying to apply the embossed, shiny effect to the word 'Elevit' and only the word Elevit. I have some text around that which I want to keep flat. In order to make the 'Elevit' shiny, I'm guessing I can play about with the roughness, but I'm not sure how to get to that stage, especially when I want to keep the other parts flat. The last pic is the nodes currently applied for the label design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix 2 *Principled BSDF* into a *Mix Shader*, use a b&w image of your font as factor. Decrease the *Roughness* of one of your *Principled BSDF* down to 0 to get full glossiness on your letter. Also plug the image into a *Bump Map* that you plug into the *Normal* input of your 2 *Principled BSDF* in order to get the relief:

[image]

If you want to emboss only some letters only, plug 2 different *Image Texture* nodes: one with all the letters into the factor of the *Mix Shader*, one with only the embossed letters into the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and it helped, but how do I do that while keeping my other writing flat? How do I do the UV editing? That's where I think I'm mostly lost at. How to do separate UV editing so I can add a bump node to one image texture, and keep the other part normal?

Comment: If you want to emboss only some letters only, plug 2 different Image Texture nodes: one with all the letters into the factor of the Mix Shader, one with only the embossed letters into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scWNg.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pPYV.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP7iy.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPCrC.png I've tried to do what you said, but for some reason it's not working (I know I'm clearly doing something wrong), also when the other text does appear, it comes out white even though the png is black. Would you be able to demonstrate it for me the way you did the previous one, I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it's more clear

Comment: Thank you so so much! You've helped me so much, I've got the style I want. I just have one little issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/u34LA.png As you can see, the bump makes the text pixelated on the inside and outside, how do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: you need to make sure that your bump image is png 32-bit float and has a resolution that is high enough, the Image Texture needs to be set to non-color, not sRGB

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been a massive help :)